# How to find the full and partial match in Mysql server

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-workbench

User gives the input and input could be a full or partial name. The query should display all the matching output. This is the code that I am using

```
c.execute("SELECT name FROM ALLNAMES WHERE Cname ='" + ('%'+ Input.get()+'%') + "';")
```

I am using python and the output is an empty list which doesn't look right.

Answer (score 1):

You need `like` instead of `=`

```
c.execute("SELECT name FROM ALLNAMES WHERE Cname LIKE '" + ('%'+ Input.get()+'%') + "';")
```

Answer (score 0):

You meant to have **like** query, not equality.
So in this case it will be:

```
c.execute("SELECT name FROM ALLNAMES WHERE Cname LIKE '"+ ('%'+ Input.get()+'%') + "';")
```

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-like/

Beware of that is not good idea to put query parameters in query string. It is vulnerable for easy sql injection. Use at least query params.